# What does "a shot to the gut" mean?

Tags: meaning

> When you fail at a goal it can be **a shot to the gut** that keeps you
>   stuck in a depressed state for a long time. 
>   (https://www.stitcher.com/podcast/brilliantside/shut-up-brain/e/54710334)
>
> (...) but the real **shot to the gut** is the one delivered at the end of
>   the episode.
>   (https://www.theworkprint.com/true-detective-review-a-shot-to-the-gut/123)

Literally, it may mean "a shot fired to the internal organs", but I wonder if there is any idiom-ish meaning. Does it mean "a critical/deadly shot"?

Comment: Perhaps in a more casual context, the writer might have used ***kick in the balls***. Or perhaps he intending the very specific "cowboy western trope" allusion to being "gut-shot" (inevitably fatal, but often agonizingly slow). (But that would be a bit *too* depressing, so maybe not! :) Really, this is "literary interpretation", not something you can look up in dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A shot to the gut" is a colloquialism that means "a painful and devastating blow that takes a long time to recover from".  "Shot" does not necessarily mean from a gun, but can also simply mean a powerful punch that feels like being shot, e.g.

> The stumbling boxer caught a hard **shot** to his jaw that dropped him to the canvas.

As FumbleFingers points out, in a less polite context the author might have used the more direct "kick to the balls".